# React set Hook from function call outside Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm testing the new React Hooks, and I've encountered a behavior I cannot fix (and comprehend neither). Basically, I have my functional component and inside it a function in which i set the hook. This function is passed to a Component rendered, and it's called from this last rendered Component using the props.
Too bad that the hooks of the parent does not update accordingly!

I know it may seems difficult to understand, but I've reproduced the error here https://codesandbox.io/s/vvwp33l7o5

As you can see, in `App` Component I've the `onResize` function that should update the `counter` hook. This function is passed to the `ResizeObserverContainerHook` Component, and from this latter is called when `ResizeObseverContainerHook` div is resized. As you can see, the `width` and the `height` variables in `onResize` function are correct, but the `counter` hook seems not to update! In fact, it stays equal to `1` forever.

I don't know, it seemes that I cannot update the hook from outside the Component ( and that's like the state in React Stateful Component, but at least I could passing a function like in this case, but it doesn't work :/ ).

Any idea how I can make that `setCounter` at like 12 of `index.js` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is a bit confused - what you're doing is fine. When it says don't call hooks from inside stuff, it means don't call the actual API's conditionally or from within loops, e.g. conditionally defining `useEffect` or `useState`.

Your problem stems from the empty array you pass to the effect in the Observer.js, because it is empty, the effect never refreshes so the closure is stale such that when the `onResize` function calls `setState`, the `counter` value will always be the initial value of zero.

You need to have that `useEffect` dependent on something so that when the component updates, it cleans up the previous effect and attaches a fresh version of the `onResize` function to the ResizeObserver.

I poked around with your sandbox a bit: https://codesandbox.io/s/x9z7k245lq?fontsize=14

It now passes down the counter state to the Observer component and the effect will run each time the counter changes. The thing is that I also added some refs to the index to track the height/width so the state doesn't always update or else it will infinitely loop. I guess you can think of that as `shouldComponentUpdate`.

It takes a while to think in hooks properly. If you want a good article to read about hooks and avoiding some pitfalls regarding empty array and stale closures, check this out: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: Uhm, now it makes more sense! But.. Would be possible to not pass `counter` to `Observer`? `Observer` should be more of a generic Component, it should just run a function when its `div` element got resized. Then, usually, that function update the state of the Component that render the `Observer`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess you could just totally not pass the `counter` down, it doesn't actually do anything so you could just not pass a second argument to the `useEffect` - I was just trying to avoid the empty `[]`. The thing to be aware of with this implementation is that it doesn't currently infinitely loop because the width/height check in the `onResize` function.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while to understand that values in effects/callbacks can be stale despite the fact they appear to be referencing the state directly. I found that blog I linked to really useful for expanding my understanding of why things don't work as I'd expect.